# Why can immutable variables be passed as arguments to functions that require mutable arguments?

Tags: variables, syntax, rust, immutability, mutable

Example code：

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    reset(a);
}

fn reset(mut b: [u32; 5]) {
    b[0] = 5;
}
```

The variable `a` is an immutable array, and the `reset` function's parameter `b` is a mutable array; intuitively I need to modify `a` to a mutable array before I can call the `reset` method, but the compiler tells me that I don't need to do this, why is this?

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    reset(a);
}

fn reset(mut b: [u32; 5]) {
    b[0] = 5;
}
```

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     let mut a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  |         ----^
  |         |
  |         help: remove this `mut`
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_mut)] on by default
```

Comment: You are passing a copy of `a` to `reset` (since it is not passed by reference), so `reset` is free to mutate this new copy.

Comment: so, this is equivalent to let mut b = memcpy(a);  right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you pass by value, you are transferring ownership of the value. No copies of the variable are required — first `main` owns it, then `reset` owns it, then it's gone<sup>1</sup>.

In Rust, when you have ownership of a variable, you can control the mutability of it. For example, you can do this:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let mut b = a;
```

You could also do the same thing inside of `reset`, although I would *not* do this, preferring to use the `mut` in the function signature:

```
fn reset(b: [u32; 5]) {
    let mut c = b;
    c[0] = 5;
}
```

See also:

- [What's the idiomatic way to pass by mutable value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31388644/155423)
- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423)

---

**1** — In *this specific case*, your type is an `[i32; 5]`, which implements the `Copy` trait. If you attempted to use `a` after giving ownership to `reset`, then an implicit copy would be made. The value of `a` would appear unchanged.

Comment: So, variables a and b point to different memory addresses, right？

Comment: @iDuanYingJie they might, but they don't have to. In your example code, the optimizer can see that `a` isn't used after it's passed to `reset`, so it might as well just use the same memory chunk for `b`. (It's tricky to tell because this code is probably optimized to a no-op because it doesn't do anything).

Comment: oh, yes! if a is uesd after it's passed to reset, i think this is equivalent to let mut b = memcpy(a); right?

Comment: @iDuanYingJie Yes, *if* `a` is used after `reset`, then a copy of `a` would be created and one passed to `reset` the other remaining in `main`.